# what could "unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fe81c721d20" 0x0000600000e3c580" mean?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I keep getting this error when I run my application, and am not sure what could be the error. Any ideas / help would be appreciated.

Comment: If you edit your post to include your code, and indicate the line where the error occurs, we might be able to explain why.

Comment: Please include the full message.

Comment: a lot of possible reason why this could happen. 

are you using storyboard? check the @IBOutlet if it's properly linked.